# Constructor connectionstring vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
#Region "Constructors"


Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("mydatabase.sdf")
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal connectionString As String)
    MyBase.New(connectionString, New AttributeMappingSource())
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal connectionString As String, ByVal mappingSource As MappingSource)
    MyBase.New(connectionString, mappingSource)
End Sub
```

in  MyBase.New("mydatabase.sdf") how can i change to MySql Database or Sql Server . i try to put connectionstring but its getting error

Comment: _What's the error?_ And what does this class inherit from?

Comment: this error http://i.imgur.com/GYfknch.png i input correct username at pass . from my DataAccessLayer

Comment: i found the solution thankyou

Comment: Please post the answer and mark it answered

Answer (score 0):

Insert Some Data in database thats my solution in myproblem